# Интерпретатор для PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm, php, jetbrains

Поставил `linux mint 17`, установил `LAMP`, скачал `phpStorm`, но для него необходим интерпретатор `php`, откуда его взять?

Лазил в папках `/usr/bin/`, `/usr/local/bin`, находил папки `php`, `php5`, а толку нет.

Где взять интерпретатор для `PHPStorm`? В винде он сразу определялся вроде...

Comment: Напишите в консоль whereis php. А потом добавьте его в настройках проекта.

Comment: нашло оно в usr/share/php - а все равно не определяет

Comment: Обычно интерпретатор валяется по адресу `/usr/bin/php` (debian, ubuntu), если его там нет - попробуйте выполнить в терминале команду `which php`, она должна выводить полный путь к исполняемому файлу. У меня (debian) в выводе `whereis` также встречается `/usr/bin/php`.

Comment: в `/usr/share/php` расположены различные воспомогательные файлы для php. И кстати, это каталог:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для тех у кого возникает такая ошибка, но сам PHP установлен:
Проверьте, выполняется ли команда php в консоли. Если нет, то выполните
sudo apt-get install php5-cli